# kendo ui custom widget angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

I have extended kendo grid

```
(function($) {
 var MyGrid = kendo.ui.Grid.extend({
    init: function(element, options) {
        kendo.ui.Grid.fn.init.call(this, element, options);
    },
    options: {
        name: 'MyGrid'
     }
    })
    kendo.ui.plugin(MyGrid);
    })(jQuery);
```

How to use custom widget in angular way.

Currently I am able to see the new directive is creating successfully, but not interpolating.

Answer (score -1):

According to the telerik forum discussion here:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/extending-the-grid-in-angular-kendo-does-not-work

> The problem seems to be in this block of code in kendo.angular.js:
>
> ```
> defadvice(kendo.ui, "plugin", function(klass, register, prefix){
>     this.next();
>     pendingPatches = $.grep(pendingPatches, function(args){
>         return !defadvice.apply(null, args);
>     });
>     createDirectives(klass, prefix == "Mobile");
> });
> ```
>
> This causes all calls to `kendo.ui.plugin()` to be intercepted and for
>   `createDirectives()` to be called on the passed in class. The problem
>   is that a kendoGrid directive has already been created for the default
>   non-extended grid, and so when `kendo.ui.plugin()` is called again for
>   the new extended grid, a second kendoGrid directive is created which
>   causes AngularJS to throw a multiple directive error.

As you can read in the official answer, Telerik doesn't support user-extended widgets.

All this being said, I'm currently investigating using Angular decorators to actually extend the directives created by Kendo for its widgets, as described here:

https://coderwall.com/p/-8vjxa/cleanly-extend-3rd-party-angularjs-directives

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13877904)

Comment: Hope it's better now.